# How to Sync more than 5000 items SharePoint Calendar to Outlook using Connect to Outlook Option

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, outlook

How to Sync more than 5000 items in SharePoint Calendar to Outlook using Connect to Outlook Option. Getting error that "HTTP 500.  The server returned the following error message:  The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator."

Any Suggestion or Workaround will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because SharePoint Online uses the Large List Resource Throttling feature. By default, the list view threshold is configured at 5,000 items.

To work around this issue, you can manage your list as the [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59).

Comment: Creating View(with less than 1000 items) and tried to “Connect to Outlook” Option. But Result is at the list level not view level. (Getting all Items in the List not Items in the View)

I believe there is no option to connect at SharePoint View level in outlook.